# Ransack not functioning for seach operation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ransack

I want to use **ransack** to search the `sales` on the basis of table names in a restaurant.

This is what my `SalesController` looks like.

```
 def index
    @q = Sale.ransack(params[:q])
    @sales = @q.result
end
```

My **index** page for model **SalesController** looks something like this:

```
= search_form_for @q, remote: true do |f|
  = f.label :tableNo_eq, 'Full Name'
  = f.search_field :tableNo_eq
  = f.submit
section
  - @sales.each.with_index do |sale,index|
    .......
    .......
```

**Problem:**

So I do get the response from ransack in the **index action in SalesController.**

I have set **binding pry**, and inspected the value for **@sales**, and it did give me result for the table name that I was looking for.

This was the log of my server.

```
[1] pry(#<SalesController>)> @sales
    Sale Load (1.4ms)  SELECT "sales".* FROM "sales" WHERE "sales"."tableNo" = 'Table 1'
```

But the problem is that, the change is not being seen in the **index view page**, and rather all the instances for sales are being showed, ie. **Sale.all**. Does this happen when ajax request is not working?

Comment: Where did you inspect the `@sales` variable? In the controller? Try inspecting it in the view: `<%= @sales.inspect %>`. Are you sure you're in the correct controller action?

Comment: Yes, i also did inspect it in the index.html.slim, and the instance variable @sales was giving me the desired output. Should i be using, ajax and display the results on a different partial? Or is it all handled by ransack itself.

Comment: So you are using an ajax request to update the index page?

Comment: I just noticed the `remote: true`, so yes it's a `:js request`. What does your `.js` response template look like?

Comment: I would suggest you leave out the `remote: true` part of the form.

Comment: Removing the remote:true helped. Thanks